# Creating new Slave without copying relay-log files from existing slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-5.5

I have a already existing master slave replication setup. I want to create a new slave but I cannot ssh  to the existing slave machine due to some issue with the slave so I cannot copy the relay log files and master.info file.
I can however connect to slave mysql using workbench and can stop slave replication if i want.
I have full acess to the master instance. Is there a way that I can create new slave ?
I am using mariadb 5.5. Thanks

Comment: You can always create new slave server from the existing Master server. Check the steps here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-setup-slaves.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Should I follow same steps, that i followed in creating the old slave..also will master have two different logs files?

Comment: Yes, the way you setup the first slave using Master. No, there should not be two different log files.